# Disabling suggestion icons in iOS 11 dock?

Tags: dock, icon, ios

In iOS 11, the Dock has gained some potentially useful features related to recent apps and app suggestens. For me however, it constitutes visual clutter, and I want to get rid of it.

Hence I disabled the "recent apps" in “Settings → General → Multitasking & Dock”.

[image: The setting is already disabled.]

However, whenever I use the alarm clock, an icon reappears.

[image: Or so I thought...]

Until I reboot, the symbol remains. To make matters worse, it doesn't just sit idle; The dock will first appear without the symbol, followed by the suggestion-area sliding in as an animation, resulting in *animated* visual clutter.

The icon is *not* related to an active alarm, but it reappears every time after the alarm has been used.

Is there any possibility to get rid of such icons entirely?

Observed on iPad Air 2 (64 GB).

Comment: It works fine for me.  I have an iPad Air 2, also, running iOS 11.1.

Comment: Do you have a daily alarm set up? I always use one-time alarms, so maybe there might be a difference.

Comment: No, I don't have any alarms setup.  I wouldn't *think* there would be a difference because Alarms are just apps, like everything else.

Answer (score 1):

That is a new feature in iOS 11. Your iPad is learning about your usage habits and recommending that app due to the time of day. There is currently no way to turn off this feature.